# How get a good approximation of integrals involving the gamma function, exponentials and the fractional part?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-series, gamma-function, fractional-part

While I was playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) I wondered how to calculate and justify an approximation of an integral involving the fractional part function, the exponential and the gamma function $$\int_0^1\left\{\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(x)}\right\}dx. $$
Thus here $\left\{x\right\}$ denotes the fractional part function, see these code

`int frac(e^(x)/Gamma(x))dx, from x=0 to 1`

and

`plot e^x/Gamma(x), from x=0 to 1`

I believe that it is feasible get the good approxiation that I've evoked using (real) analysis, but I am not sure of my strategy.

> **Question.** What is a good method to calculate and justify a good approximation of the integral $$\int_0^1\left\{\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(x)}\right\}dx\,?$$ **Many thanks.**

Comment: you can use Weierstrass infinite product for $1/\Gamma$

Comment: Yours seems a very good hint @Masacroso but I am not able to get the result. My strategy was more simple and without results.

Comment: What exactly *was* your strategy, just typing it into Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I'm sorry was disconnected @ProfessorVector , my strategy was to combine with the definition of fractional part function, but also with the thought of do a comparison of  the numerator and denominator functions, or try to combine with the Fourier  expansion of the fractional part. But as I've said I have no results.

Comment: I think a good strategy would be to ignore the fractional part at first and calculate $\displaystyle I_1=\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(x)}\,dx$, first. Then,you subtract the integral over the integer part, being $2-x_1-x_2$, obviously, where $x_k$ is the solution of $\dfrac{e^x}{\Gamma(x)}=k$. All that can be done with standard numerical methods, since $\dfrac{e^x}{\Gamma(x)}$ is a very regular function (entire, actually). The result is $I_1+x_1+x_2-2=0.42384987265144912254672336585425778176$. The only problem with that is: who needs such a result?

Comment: Many thanks for your remarks, now I read these @ProfessorVector